# Graphviz Dot Edge Ports for Family Tree

Tags: tree, graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I am *very* close to being able to generate a family tree that doesn't look terrible, but I'm running into the following problem.

```
//file: tree.dot
digraph {
    edge [dir=none];
    node [
        fillcolor="black",fixedsize=true,shape=box,
        style="rounded,filled",width=2.0
    ];
    splines=ortho;
    // GEN -01
    {
        rank=same; rankdir=LR;
        "Grandfather" [regular=0];
        m0002 [
            label="",shape=diamond,regular=0,height=0.25,
            width=0.25,style="filled",
        ];
        "Grandmother" [regular=0];
        {
            rank=same; rankdir=LR;
            "Grandfather" -> m0002 -> "Grandmother";
        }
    }
    m0002 -> c0001;
    // GEN  00
    {
        rank=same; rankdir=LR;
        c0000 [
            label="",shape=circle, regular=0, height=0.05,
            width=0.05,style="filled"
        ];
        c0001 [
            label="",shape=circle, regular=0, height=0.05,
            width=0.05,style="filled"
        ];
        c0002 [
            label="",shape=circle, regular=0, height=0.05,
            width=0.05, style="filled"
        ];
        {
            rank=same; rankdir=LR;
            c0000 -> c0001 -> c0002;
        }
    }
    {
        rank=same; rankdir=LR;
        "Son 1" [regular=0];
        "Daughter 1" [regular=0];
        "Son 2" [regular=0];
        m0000 [
            label="",shape=diamond,regular=0,height=0.25,
            width=0.25,style="filled"
        ];
        "Other Daughter 1" [regular=0];
        "Other Son 1" [regular=0];
        "Other Other Son 1" [regular=0];
        m0001 [
            label="",shape=diamond,regular=0,height=0.25,
            width=0.25, style="filled"
        ];
        "Other Daughter 2" [regular=0];
        {
            rank=same; rankdir=LR;
            "Son 2" -> m0000 -> "Other Daughter 1";
            "Other Other Son 1" -> m0001 -> "Other Daughter 2";
        }
    }
    c0000 -> "Son 1";
    c0001 -> "Daughter 1";
    c0002 -> "Son 2";
}
```

The above code produces [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pep7P.png), which has edges to **Son 1** and **Son 2** that look weird. I ran it with `dot -Tpng tree.dot`. When I run the same code [here](http://www.webgraphviz.com/), I get the [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpzAO.png).

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the expected output without using the web interface (I will have potentially hundreds of nodes)? In other words, how can I get **c0000** and **c0002** to line up with the center of **Son 1** and **Son 2**, respectively, so that their edges attach to the center top of the nodes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Graphviz, how do I align an edge to the top center of a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504703/in-graphviz-how-do-i-align-an-edge-to-the-top-center-of-a-node)

Comment: @greedybuddha I tried both of those previously; neither works.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify where the edge connects using *ports* which use compass directions, n, s, e, w, nw, ne, sw, se.

Changing the following lines at the end of your dot file to include ports.

```
    c0000 -> "Son 1" [headport=ne];
    c0002 -> "Son 2":nw; // Shorthand for [headport=nw]
```

results in this image

[image: Edge links are more toward center]

This doesn't put the edges dead center, and changing the port locations to `n` doesn't work. But it no longer has edges pointing to an empty corner like your original. Part of GraphViz's utility is the autolayout but sometimes it seems to override user decisions (or is a bug).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too; it's better, but still not perfect.  I've tried playing with different arguments for `splines` as well, but no luck.